# Dynamically Creating and Executing Queries in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, azure-synapse

I need to get the row counts of all tables in Azure Synapse Serverless SQL. I can't use stored procedures, nor can I use DMV. I have a query that creates the list of all fully qualified table names for analysis, but I'm struggling with the next step of ACTUALLY executing the queries. I don't think I will be able to do it directly in SQL Server, as I cannot run dynamic SQL.

My ideal solution would be something in Power Query. Again, I have a list (and parameter) set up with all of the names. I only need some way to have it execute SELECT Count(*) from [TableName] for each -- please help me!

I've done research on Dynamic M queries, but I must be missing something.

More notes: This needs to be direct query, native queries only.

I've tried pretty much everything in SQL that I can find on Stack Overflow or in Synapse documentation, but I need help with the power query.
Dynamic SQL XXX
Stored Procedures XXX
Dynamic Management Views XXX

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach (untested) where you could do it as one SQL for all the tables in your list. You can then use the result of this query for your SQL statement.

```
let
    Source = Table.SelectColumns(SQLTable,{"TableName"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each "SELECT """& [TableName] &""" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM " & [TableName]),
    #"SQL command" = Text.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom], "#(lf) UNION #(lf)")
in
    #"SQL command"
```

- Update `SQLTable` to your query with the list of table names.
- Update `"TableName"` and `[TableName]` to the column name that has your table name.

This should give you a SQL command similar to:

```sql
SELECT "Alpha" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM Alpha
UNION
SELECT "Beta" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM Beta
UNION
SELECT "Charlie" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM Charlie
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?